# Calculating the number of disconnected components of a NetworkX graph

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

Starting with a randomly generated tree, I want to consider each node of the tree and potentially remove it with some probability `p`. Since trees have no cycles and there is a unique path between any pair of nodes, the removal of a node should leave `d` disconnected trees in its wake, where `d` is the degree of that node.

My question is, once I've done this for the whole graph, how can I check how many of these unconnected segments there are?

```
import networkx as nx
import random as rand

n = 20
p = 0.1

G = nx.random_tree(n)
for i in range(0, n):
    if rand.random() < p:
        G.remove_node(i)

x = G.count_disconnected_components() # is there anything that accomplishes this?
```

For example, for this graph, `G.count_disconnected_components()` should return 3.
 [image: graph with three unconnected components]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me you actually want to count the number of connected parts. Try [`number_connected_components`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.number_connected_components.html):

```
print(list(nx.connected_components(G)))
print(nx.number_connected_components(G))
```